RStudio: Rendering to docx creates a trailing 'X' in reference list entries (only) if using a docx template
PopOS based on Ubuntu 24.04. 
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) 
Rstudio: 2024.09.0 Build 375 
pandoc 2.9.2.1 
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.20, texmath 0.12.0.2, skylighting 0.8.5 
pandoc-citeproc 0.17.0.1

When rendering a docx from a quarto markdown file, every entry in the Reference list is trailed by a mysterious and enigmatic 'X' (buried treasure?), like this: 1.    O’Neill S, Manniche C, Graven-Nielsen T, Arendt-Nielsen L. Association between a composite score of pain sensitivity and clinical parameters in low-back pain. Clin J Pain. 2014 Oct;30(10):831–8. X -- note the trailing 'X'.
Conversely, when manually running the markdown file (yaml: keep-md: true), which is fact identical to the quarto-md file through pandoc, the output is as expected (without the trailing X). Pandoc command: pandoc temp_quarto.docx.md -o temp_quarto.docx --bibliography=temp_bibtex.bib --csl=vancouver-brackets.csl --reference-doc=KorJPain_template.docx
Note, that the template, the bibtex and the csl files are the same in both scenarios.
Also, when rendering from RStudio, without a docx-template (comment in/out lines 3-6 in Quarto YAML), the problem X goes away.
I therefor deduce, that the trailing X must somehow be the result of the way RStudio calls pandoc ... am I wrong? Any ideas where the problem lies?
Minimal working example:
The Quarto markdown file:
---
title: "Untitled"
format:
 docx:
   reference-doc: "KorJPain_template.docx"
# format: docx
editor: source
keep-md: true
csl: vancouver-brackets.csl
bibliography: temp_bibtex.bib
---

Some text with a citation[@oneillAssociationCompositeScore2014].

# References

The vancouver-brackets.csl file is sourced here.
The docx-template file (download), is as simple as can be: A new word (2016) file, with a single line of text with each of the style definitions: 'Title', Subtitle', Heading', 'Heading 2', 'Heading 3', 'Heading 4' and 'Normal' text.
The bibtex file used is:
@article{oneillAssociationCompositeScore2014,
  title = {Association between a Composite Score of Pain Sensitivity and Clinical Parameters in Low-Back Pain},
  author = {O'Neill, S{\o}ren and Manniche, Claus and {Graven-Nielsen}, Thomas and {Arendt-Nielsen}, Lars},
  year = {2014},
  month = oct,
  journal = {Clin. J. Pain},
  volume = {30},
  number = {10},
  pages = {831--838},
  issn = {1536-5409},
  doi = {10.1097/AJP.0000000000000042},
  langid = {english},
  pmid = {24121529}
}

Uninformative output from RStudio background job pane:
==> quarto preview temp_quarto.qmd --to docx --no-watch-inputs --no-browse

pandoc 
  to: docx
  output-file: temp_quarto.docx
  default-image-extension: png
  reference-doc: KorJPain_template.docx
  
metadata
  title: Untitled
  editor: source
  csl: vancouver-brackets.csl
  bibliography:
    - temp_bibtex.bib
  
Output created: temp_quarto.docx

Watching files for changes
Browse at http://localhost:3177/

